# Vertically align the absolutely positioned content of ::before to match parent’s baseline

Tags: css

What is the best or right way to vertically align small absolutely positioned ::before content so that its baseline lines up with the parent’s text?

In this snippet, I want the “XL” to have the same baseline as the “Lorem ipsum”. Just tweaking top: would be too fragile.

```css
body {margin: 0 30px; position: relative}

p {background-color: lightblue}

p::before {content: "XL"; font-size: 75%; position: absolute; right: 100%; background-color: lightgray}
```

```html
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi in dictum purus. Etiam accumsan quam et turpis elementum, in tempor.  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Correct answer**: use `line-height` and use `em`.

You've come across a classic example when you want to use the text baseline as `transform-origin` of your element. I recommend [this reading](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/) to understand limitations.

Also, in your current solution you're relying on the width of the closest relatively positioned ancestor to move the `:before`. You don't really need that. You can safely leave it at it's current position (top left corner of parent) and simply move it 100% of its own width towards the left:

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="range"]').addEventListener('input', function(){
  document.body.style.fontSize = this.value + 'px'
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 24px 0 0 1em;
  font-size: 18px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

p::before {
  content: "XL";
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-size: 75%;           
  line-height: 1.75em; 
}

input[type=range] {
  width: 80vw;
  left: 10vw;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi in dictum purus. Etiam accumsan quam et turpis elementum, in tempor. </p>

<input type="range" value="18" step=".01" min="10" max="84">
```

---

**Initial answer** (when I believed you simply want to align to bottom):

You need to give the parent `position:relative;` and child: `bottom: 0`:

```css
body {padding: 0 30px; }

p {
  background-color: lightblue; 
  position: relative
  }

p::before {
  content: "XL"; 
  font-size: 75%; 
  position: absolute; 
  right: 100%; 
  background-color: lightgray;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi in dictum purus. Etiam accumsan quam et turpis elementum, in tempor.  </p>
</body>
```

Out of scope: **don't** use `margin` on `<body>`. Use `padding` instead.

Comment: That works only if the Lorem ipsum is on one line. But it could be long. I need the XL to align with the first letter of the Lorem ipsum.

Comment: In that case `height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.75em;` is the way to go. That wasn't clear from your requirements. I understood you want it aligned to bottom. My bad.

Comment: Correct answer here being: **Don't' use `px`, use `em`**.

Comment: How would you adjust height and line-height for different font sizes?

Comment: Oops, I meant different font-size values not for the body text but for content of the ::before — say 50%, or 80%, or 8px.

Comment: You'd need to update the `line-height` based on percentage and font used. Good luck with that! Once you find the formula for your currently used font, you're in the clear, as long as you successfully load the same font in all browsers (which shouldn't be a problem nowadays). Why do I get the feeling your question is not really asked to find a technical solution to an actual problem, but more of a rant at how CSS is currently unable to determine the exact position of the baseline relative to its line height? I feel I was wrong trying to help here.

Comment: No rant. It’s a real problem on a real template. I just need some heuristic so the marginal text lines up with the body even when users configure in different fonts and different sizes. +1 for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would adjust the `line-height`

```css
div {
  margin: 0 30px;
  position: relative
}

p {
  background-color: lightblue
}

p::before {
  content: "XL";
  font-size: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  line-height:1.75;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi in dictum purus. Etiam accumsan quam et turpis elementum, in tempor. </p>
</div>

<div style="font-size:20px;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi in dictum purus. Etiam accumsan quam et turpis elementum, in tempor. </p>
</div>

<div style="font-size:35px;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi in dictum purus. Etiam accumsan quam et turpis elementum, in tempor. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the right relationship for line-height? What should line-height be if font-size is 60%? 80%?

Comment: @JPM a good question :) to be honest I know there is a relation but it is a bit complicated to figure out ... I simply found this value by doing some tests. I will think about it and update if I found the formula

Comment: It differs based on font.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu even if it's not the same for each font we can say that for each font there is for sure a relation between the percentage we use in the font-size and the line-height and this relation will differ between each font.